# Flask CSRF session token is missing

Tags: session, flask, csrf

**Goal**

I'm trying to achieve session terminate/expire on browser close and time-restricted session. My approach to this requires `app.permanent = False`. So that when a browser is closed, the session gets terminated. On top of this, I want to also apply time-limited session. My plan was to do `session['expiry'] = 2018-07-21`  in `before_request` function and terminate the session if it is expired.

**Problem**

The problem that I'm facing is that, when I try to login (currently using flask_security out of the box), I get a 400 error `CSRF session token is missing`. I have tried `{{ form.hidden_tag() }}, {{ form.csrf_token }}` but nothing seems to work. It works only when I remove the `csrf=CSRFProtect(app)`. I have server-side session implemented using Flask session_store using SQLAlchemySessionInterface.

**Question**

1. Is it even possible to implement session terminate on browser close and time-restricted session together? If this is possible, are there any other approaches that I can take other than what I've described above? (Also tried JS onunload).
2. Any idea on what is going on with CSRF session token missing? I assume it is bit different from CSRF token missing and the google search didn't return much.

**Minimized Code**

**View - login_view.py**

```
from app import app
from flask import render_template, redirect
from flask_login import current_user
from flask_security import login_user, current_user
from login_form import LoginForm

@app.route('/login_test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login_test():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        if user is None or not user.check_password(form.password.data):
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        login_user(user)
        return redirect(url_for('main_bp.index_entry'))
    return render_template('login_test.html', title='Sign In', form=form)
```

**login_form.py**

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, validators, PasswordField

# bare minimum of form class for testing

class LoginForm(FlaskForm):

    email = StringField('Email', [validators.DataRequired()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', [validators.DataRequired()])
```

**HTML - login_test.html**

```
<form action="{{ url_for('.login_test') }}" method="POST" name="user_login" autocomplete="off">


    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}


    {{ form.email(class_='form-control login_form', placeholder='Email (Required)') }}


    {{ form.password(class_='form-control login_form', placeholder='Password (Required)') }}


    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

**app/__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect
from flask_sessionstore import Session
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_sessionstore import Session

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='static', instance_relative_config=True)
app.config.from_pyfile('dev_app_config.py') 
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
app.config['SESSION_SQLALCHEMY'] = db
session = Session(app)
csrf = CSRFProtect(app)
# session.app.session_interface.db.create_all()
```

**run.py**

Declaring `session.permanent = False` as below does not have any effect, the `session.permanent` still gets set up to True. I'm just displaying `before_request` since it seems that it is the most accepted way of declaring `session.permanent`.

```
from app import app, session
@app.before_request
def make_session_permanent():
    session.permanent = False
```

**instance/dev_app_config.py**

Instead of above `before_request`, I've declared session.permanent in application's config and doing it this way actually makes the session.permanent to False

```
SECRET_KEY = 'asdf3333dsf....manymore'
WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = True
SESSION_PERMANENT = False
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = "127.0.0.1:5000"
```

Comment: Some code is missing to reproduce the context, please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Added more code and import